# bitwise OR of two hexadecimal number in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, bitwise-or

I will receive "n" number of four byte of hexadecimal value as a string data type in an array in JavaScript. I have to perform a bitwise ORing on all the "n" numbers and provide the final value in same format (i.e hexadecimal value and string data type). I have posted my code as sample for "n"=2.

```
var TTL_ON = ["0xFF208D32","0x5E2C3301"];
TTL_ON="0x"+decimalToHex(eval(TTL_ON.join("|")),8);
WScript.Echo("TTL_ON "+TTL_ON);

function decimalToHex(Decimal, Padding) {
if (decimalToHex.arguments.length != decimalToHex.length) {
    return;
} else {
    var hex = Number(Decimal).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    Padding = typeof(Padding) === "undefined" || Padding === null ? Padding = 2 : Padding;
    while (hex.length < Padding) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex;
}
}
```

The expected output was "0xFF2CBF33"

The output I received was "0x0-D340CD".

Thanks Alex.k has explained source of problem. can anyone provide solution for my problem?

Comment: Same reason that 0xFF208D32 | 0 is -14643918, see [Why is JavaScript bitwise OR behaving strangely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329899/why-is-javascript-bitwise-or-behaving-strangely) - using a big int library is one workaround.